# Loading SWF file in Haxe?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, haxe

I am a new comer to Haxe, I was wondering about loading SWF files and using assets inside them.
the following questions have no clear answer to me yet, they all about using assets from external swf files ( export for ActionScript, with a known Class name to use )

1. If I am targeting HTML5, then how would I load a SWF file and use assets inside it? can I instantiate Classes inside the external SWF file?
2. In general, will loading a SWF file and using assets inside it easy in Haxe? What about frames inside the external SWF file, can I for example say gotoAndStop(frame_number) of the loaded swf file?

Any recommendations ? links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i know , option 1 is not possible. you cannot use swf assets targeting js .
even with NME wich support html5 . swf asset is not supported.

for loading swf at runtime in order to access the movieClips ,it'as a bit tricky but it works

i prefer compilation-time library:
Concerning loading swf library at compilation-time.Using swf-lib directive. the workflow is good enough to use it.
quick tip: use composition for your  binded classes (a:bind).
see this doc : http://haxe.org/doc/flash/0_start

Comment: But, why loading swf at runtime in order to access the movieClips is a bit tricky? isn't Haxe better than AS3? shouldn't it load movies as AS3 would?